# youtube embed video fullscreen with object tag

Tags: html, youtube, youtube-api, html4

I know that youtube now uses `<iframe>` tag for embeded videos insted of `<object>`. I have some legacy code that requires fullscreen mode with `<object>` tag implementation. Is it possible to somehow force native fullscreen mode with `<object>` tag?

```
<object
    width="560"
    height="350" 
    data="http://www.youtube.com/v/B8IIyYpqb5w&amp;fs=1" 
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash">

    <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
    <param name="src" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/B8IIyYpqb5w&amp;fs=1" />
</object>
```

I also tried `&fs=1` and `&fullscreen=1` parameter in URL but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you have to use `<iframe>` instead. You are experiencing this limitation due to **`<object>`** and **`<embed>`** were deprecated from January 2015 according to [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_youtube.asp).

Base on this snippet:

```
<body>

<div>
  <object
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
    data="http://www.youtube.com/v/Wd1Iz6j4WC0"
    width="425"
    height="355">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/Wd1Iz6j4WC0">
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
  </object>
</div>

<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Wd1Iz6j4WC0" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>


</body>
```

The object tag keeps on experiencing "Fullscreen is unavailable" while the iframe function as intended.

Or you could use this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

> The sample HTML page below creates an embedded player that will load a video, play it for six seconds, and then stop the playback.

Hope this help.

Comment: Object element was not obsoleted (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/iframe-embed-object.html#the-object-element)