# AngularJS - Dynamic Youtube URL do not properly work with Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in AngularJS and I am fetching a data from a Rest API, sample data is given below.

```
{
    "error": false,
    "videos": [
        {
            "video_category": "ABC Category",
            "title": "Test Video",
            "video_links": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "video_link": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/bNI4Jws68m0"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "video_link": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/tB8tACPZ4pc"
                }
            ],
            "video_tags": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "ABC Tag"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "DEC Tag"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "video_category": "XYZ Category",
            "title": "My Test Video",
            "video_links": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "video_link": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/6SS3tK1NMsE"
                }
            ],
            "video_tags": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "GDF Tag"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status_code": 200
}
```

My AngularJS code is below.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.
controller("AppController", function($scope, $http) {

    var url = 'http://example.com/api/';

        // Get Service for Free Education Page        
        $http.get(url+'my_api_url').
        then(function(response) {
            $scope.videos = response.data.videos;
        });        

});
```

My HTML Code is below.

```
<section ng-repeat="video in videos">
    <h5>{{ video.video_category }}</h5>                     
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="links in video.video_links">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <object 
             data="{{ links.video_link }}">
            <param name="movie" value="{{ links.video_link }}">
            <param name="allowFullScreen" mozallowfullscreen="mozallowfullscreen" msallowfullscreen="msallowfullscreen" oallowfullscreen="oallowfullscreen" webkitallowfullscreen="webkitallowfullscreen" value="true"></param>
            </object>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="list-inline Tags">
    <li ng-repeat="tag in video.video_tags">{{ tag.name }}</li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Now My Issue is that everything is work fine. but Allowfullscreen did not work. When I click on full screen option it is giving **Full Screen is Unavailable** I am trying but unfortunately unable to resolve this issue.

Really appreciated if anyone can help.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44208815/youtube-embed-video-fullscreen-with-object-tag

Comment: I have tried above solution but it does not work for me.

Comment: Did you put the embed url in the `<iframe>`?

Comment: I have written such type of that --- <iframe src="{{ links.video_link }}" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>

Comment: Seems to be a [known issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/helpconsole/k37jVm9yUr4). Advice you to move past it :|